# Como criar sublistas com elementos numéricos que estão em uma sequência?

Tags: python, lista

Amigos, imaginem uma lista:

```
lista = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14]
```

Teria como eu criar sublistas somente com os elementos que estão em sequência? Por exemplo, nesse caso ficaria:

```
lista = [[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [6, 6, 7], [11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14]]
```

Sendo que a quantidade de sublistas pode variar, de acordo com a quantidade de elementos da lista.

Aguardo e de já agradeço.

Comment: Amigo, poderia dar mais detalhes? Qual linguagem? Qual é a lógica para separar os elementos em sublistas? Você se refere á `List<T>` quando diz "lista" ou se refere á um `Array`?

Comment: Se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, poderia marcá-la como aceita/correta ao clicar no ✅ ao lado da resposta que contém a melhor solução? Se fizer isso, sua pergunta também será marcada como solucionada/resolvida.

Answer (score 3):

Inicialmente a pergunta não especificava a linguagem desejada, e por isso tinha feito somente em Javascript. Agora que o autor especificou que quer Python, tenho implementações em Python, Javascript e Java.

## Python

```python
def dividir(array):
    resultado = []
    nada = {}
    parte = []
    ultima = nada
    for elemento in array:
        if len(parte) > 0 and (ultima == nada or (elemento != ultima and elemento != ultima + 1)):
           resultado.append(parte)
           parte = []
        parte.append(elemento)
        ultima = elemento
    if len(parte) > 0:
        resultado.append(parte)
    return resultado

# Teste
array = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14]
lista = dividir(array)
print(lista);
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/9K2ASQ)

## Javascript

```js
function dividir(array) {
    var resultado = [];
    var nada = {};
    var parte = [];
    var ultima = nada;
    for (var idx in array) {
        var elemento = array[idx];
        if (parte.length > 0 && (ultima === nada || (elemento !== ultima && elemento !== ultima + 1))) {
           resultado.push(parte);
           parte = [];
        }
        parte.push(elemento);
        ultima = elemento;
    }
    if (parte.length > 0) resultado.push(parte);
    return resultado;
}

// Teste
var array = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14];
var lista = dividir(array);
console.log(lista);
```

Clique no botão azul "Executar" acima para testar.

## Java

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    private static List<List<Integer>> dividir(int... array) {
        List<Integer> lista = IntStream.of(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return dividir(lista);
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> dividir(List<Integer> lista) {
        List<List<Integer>> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> parte = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer ultima = null;
        for (Integer i : lista) {
            int elemento = i;
            if (!parte.isEmpty() && (ultima == null || (elemento != ultima && elemento != ultima + 1))) {
                resultado.add(parte);
                parte = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            parte.add(elemento);
            ultima = elemento;
        }
        if (!parte.isEmpty()) resultado.add(parte);
        return resultado;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14};
        List<List<Integer>> lista = dividir(array);
        System.out.println(lista);
    }
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/lK4GDe)

Comment: Vixe amigo, preciso em python, mas muito obrigado.

Comment: @FranciscoGerson Ok. Acrescentei a tag [python] na sua pergunta para deixar isso claro.

Comment: @FranciscoGerson Resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 2):

Se você puder usar a biblioteca [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) (que eu fortemente aconselho), uma maneira *muito simples* de conseguir isso é com o seguinte código:

```
# Sua lista original
lista = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14]

# Importa a biblioteca NumPy
import numpy as np

# Separa em grupos usando como índices da separação os locais onde ocorre uma
# diferença entre o item atual e o próximo maior do que 1
grupos = np.split(lista, [i+1 for i,j in enumerate(np.diff(lista)) if j > 1])

# Imprime os grupos produzidos
for i, g in enumerate(grupos):
    print('Grupo #{}: {}'.format(i, g.tolist()))
```

Ele produz a seguinte saída:

```
Grupo #0: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
Grupo #1: [6, 6, 7]
Grupo #2: [11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14]
```

A parte essencial do código é a linha com a chamada de [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html). Ela recebe como parâmetro a lista a ser dividida e uma outra lista com os *índices* onde a divisão deve ocorrer. Esses índices são localizados usando outra função do NumPy que é [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), que calcula automaticamente as diferenças entre um item da lista e o seguinte. Basicamente você só precisa dessa linha (além da importação).

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/DKKS3P).

Comment: Luiz, apareceu mais um porém aqui rapaz, o seu código funcionou beleza, acontece que eu tou trabalhando com coordenadas x e y, na verdade a minha lista é uma lista de listas, onde eu quero separar as sublistas pelo primeiro elemento (x) mas preciso em seguida do segundo elemento (y) para fazer um cálculo, entende? Assim a lista seria essa entao: lista = [(13, 38), (14, 35), (14, 36), (15, 33), (15, 34), (15, 35), (15, 36), (18, 31), (18, 32), (19, 33), (22, 34), (22, 29), (23, 30), (23, 31), (24, 32)]. Assim:  "lista[tenho que separar as sublistas baseado nesse] [mas preciso desse depois]"

Comment: Colega, duas coisas: 1) Essa parece ser uma pergunta totalmente diferente da que você fez. Eu respondi o que você perguntou. Se não era essa a sua dúvida, deveria ter perguntado o que queria saber diretamente. Se tem outra dúvida, abra outra pergunta. 2) Eu não entendi o que você está perguntando agora e, principalmente, não entendi a relação das duas perguntas (se é que há uma) porque o formato e o conteúdo não tem nada a ver com o exemplo que você usou antes.

Comment: Ok vou abrir outro post e me explicar melhor, desculpe.