# Como criar sublistas com pares de elementos (x,y), em que o primeiro deles (x) está em uma sequência?

Tags: python-2.7, lista

Amigos, imaginem uma lista formada por pares de elementos (x,y):

> `lista = [(13, 38), (14, 35), (14, 36), (15, 33), (15, 34), (15, 35),
>   (15, 36), (18, 31), (18, 32), (19, 33), (22, 34), (22, 29), (23, 30),
>   (23, 31), (24, 32)]`

Teria como eu criar sublistas com os pares de elementos em que o primeiro elemento (x) está em sequência? Por exemplo, nesse caso ficaria:

> `lista = [[(13, 38), (14, 35), (14, 36), (15, 33), (15, 34), (15, 35),
>   (15, 36)], [(18, 31), (18, 32), (19, 33)], [(22, 34), (22, 29), (23,
>   30), (23, 31), (24, 32)]]`

---

> `Grupo #0: [(13, 38), (14, 35), (14, 36), (15, 33), (15, 34), (15, 35),
>   (15, 36)] Grupo #1: [(18, 31), (18, 32), (19, 33)] Grupo #2: [(22,
>   34), (22, 29), (23, 30), (23, 31), (24, 32)]`

Sendo que a quantidade de sublistas pode variar, de acordo com a quantidade de elementos da lista.

Um membro aqui do fórum me [passou o código abaixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/183473/73), eu inicialmente [em outro post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183382/73) não me expressei corretamente e passei uma lista simples, funcionou muito bem, a questão é que irei trabalhar com pares de elementos, quem puder ajudar agradeço:

```
# Sua lista original

lista = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14]

# Importa a biblioteca NumPy

import numpy as np

# Separa em grupos usando como índices da separação os locais onde ocorre uma
# diferença entre o item atual e o próximo maior do que 1

grupos = np.split(lista, [i+1 for i,j in enumerate(np.diff(lista)) if j > 1])

# Imprime os grupos produzidos

for i, g in enumerate(grupos):
    print('Grupo #{}: {}'.format(i, g.tolist()))
```

Ele produz a seguinte saída:

```
Grupo #0: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
Grupo #1: [6, 6, 7]
Grupo #2: [11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14]
```

Comment: Francisco, você realmente tá com bastante dificuldade de se explicar (nesta pergunta, o seu "como ficaria" é exatamente igual à lista postada imediatamente antes; somente alguém que leu as duas perguntas separadamente vai conseguir te entender). Isso, aliás, é outra coisa importante: se for citar outra postagem coloque o link pra ela.

Comment: O que vc quer, na verdade, é fazer a mesma separação em grupos feita lá [na sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183382/73), só que considerando os pares. É isso?

Comment: Respondi. Ah, no futuro, tome mais cuidado nas explicações. Se as pessoas não entenderem a sua pergunta, você só torna mais difícil conseguir alguém pra te ajudar. :)

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183382/132

Comment: Respondeu sim, próxima vez tentarei ser mais claro, desculpa.

Answer (score 2):

> Eu [sugeri que você abrisse outra
>   pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183382/como-criar-sublistas-com-elementos-num%c3%a9ricos-que-est%c3%a3o-em-uma-sequ%c3%aancia#comment379794_183473)
>   porque entendi que o problema era outro. Mas ele é essencialmente o
>   mesmo que o da [sua pergunta
>   original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183382/73), você só cometeu o
>   erro de não deixar claro lá que a sua estrutura não era
>   unidimensional.
>
> Eu considerei marcar essa como duplicata daquela e te pedir pra
>   corrigir a pergunta lá, mas ela invalidaria outra resposta que vc já
>   tem. Por isso, vou responder aqui novamente.

O princípio é **exatamente o mesmo** da [minha resposta lá da sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/183473/73). Você só precisa considerar que a sua lista agora tem 2 dimensões. O que muda no código é essa linha:

```
grupos = np.split(lista, [i+1 for i,j in enumerate(np.diff(lista, axis=0)) if j[0] > 1])
```

As diferenças são:

1. A chamada de `np.diff` agora inclui um parâmetro `axis=0`, para indicar que as diferenças devem ser calculadas considerando o primeiro eixo. Isso gerará como resultado as diferenças entre x e entre y, também em uma lista bidimensional (`[[ 1, -3], [ 0,  1], [ 1, -3], [ 0,  1], [ 0,  1], [ 0,  1], [ 3, -5],[ 0,  1], [ 1,  1], [ 3,  1], [ 0, -5], [ 1,  1], [ 0,  1], [ 1,  1]]`).
2. A verificação agora compara `j[0] > 1` ao invés de comparar `j > 1`, já que `j` agora é uma tupla com dois números (x, y), e a posição 0 é o valor de x.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/hCSr22).